# Swift: Associative Arrays in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Pretty new so apologies if this is noobish.

I'm trying to get the key and the value from an associative array to print out as the label text in a cell.

At the moment I have the array:

```
let users = ["John","James","Liam"]
```

and I am getting the value for the cell text like so:

```
cell.textLabel!.text = self.users[indexPath.row]
```

Which will give me rows of the names in. I am struggling when I add in user ages like so

```
lets users = ["John" : 36, "James": 12, "Liam": 30]
```

I get this error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

How do I get the cell text to display both the name and age?

Comment: You need to define a dictionary and with ages and names and in each cell get from the dictionary the age with the name as key, or you can define a model with name and age like Person and put and use as your datasource Array, which I think is better

Comment: Note that `["John" : 36, "James": 12, "Liam": 30]` is a *Dictionary,* which is an *unordered* collection of key-value associations. Asking for the first (second, ...) element is possible, but does not make much sense in Swift.

Comment: Why not use a model to handle this? @JamesG

Comment: @ReinierMelian I am unsure how to do this but I am willing to learn, would you be willing to show me and explain the reasoning??

Comment: @JamesG added an answer

Comment: Given that dictionaries are unordered, it's generally not a suitable model structure for a table view (because in tables, we generally _do_ care about the order). I'd suggest an array of custom objects as suggested by HuaTham.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to refer to the data via an array, there are at least two ways you can easily accomplish this. Create a Person object like in the comments, or you can quickly use a tuple structure. The following code works in Xcode Playground (Swift 3, 4).

```
// - First Approach
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

let users = [Person(name: "John", age: 36), Person(name: "James", age: 12), Person(name: "Liam", age: 30)]

// say indexPath.row = 0
print("name: \(users[0].name), age: \(users[0].age)")           // name: John, age: 36

// - Second Approach
let usersTuple = [("John", 36), ("James", 12), ("Liam", 30)]
print("name: \(usersTuple[0].0), age: \(usersTuple[0].1)")      // name: John, age: 36
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `dictionary` and with ages and names and in each cell get from the dictionary the age with the name as key, or you can define a model with name and age like `Person` and put and use as your datasource `Array`, which I think is better

```
class Person{
    var age : Int = 0
    var name : String = ""

    init(name:String,age:Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

declare an array of `Person` in your ViewController

```
var users = [Person(name: "John", age: 36),Person(name: "James", age: 12),Person(name: "Liam", age: 30)]
```

In the `cellForRow` method

```
let currUser = self.users[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = currUser.name + "Age: \(currUser.age)"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're coming from a PHP style background, it can be confusing that dictionaries look like associated arrays but there's no way to reference them by index like in PHP. You'll need to reference by the key (the string) or convert them into something which you can retrieve later.

Luckily in Swift you can just use something called a `tuple`, which looks like this:

`let user = ("John", 36)`

And you reference the values like this:

```
let name = user.0
let age = user.1
```

You can store tuples in arrays, so you can do this:

```
let users = [("John", 36), ("James", 12)]
let johnAge = users[0].1
```

You can also give the tuple named parameters but by this point you might as well create a struct. Here's what it looks like anyway:

```
let user = (name: "John", age: 36)
let johnAge = user.age
```

Another neat trick with tuples is that if you `typealias` it you can create it the same way you would a struct, without having to device the properties individually, like this:

```
typealias User = (name: String, age: Int)
let john = User(name: "John", age: 36)
```

By this point it's just a case of saving a few lines of code but it really depends on how lightweight you need the user object to be. You wouldn't be able to make it conform to anything in the future, which is why a struct can be a better option. If all you ever need is a lightweight object, tuples are great.

Comment: Defining a proper `struct` type, like HuaTham suggested, is much better approach.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ it's a better approach? For the benefit of anyone finding this question and answer, it's a good idea to provide reasons rather than opinion.

Comment: Because the above is reliant on the programmer remembering the names, order, or number of properties every time you use it. With a `struct`, the compiler enforces this for you. The approach outlined here is really fragile.

Comment: That's a better comment and makes more sense. You don't have to remember the order if you use named parameters though and you can `typealias` it which gives you struct-like initialisers without having to create a `struct`. Developers will always have to remember the _names_ of properties even for a `struct`, so that point doesn't make sense.